# Unhandled Rejection Error - why? // Promise Chain Design decision?

Tags: javascript, promise

A) See please the code below.
If I use line `// 1` I get the `onError` method called, that's OK.
But if I use line `// 2` (and comment out `// 1`), then `onError` is still called but there is also an unhandled rejection error. Why? This kind of forces me to do chaining as in `// 1`. If I don't do chaining but call `catch` on the original promise then I get the `unhandled rejection error`.

B) Why the calls `p.then` and `p.catch` do not return the original promise `p`? I find this weird. In all libs which I have seen to allow chaining, the original object (i.e. the `this` object) is returned. In JavaScript when we do `promise1.then(...)` a new `promise2` is a returned which is not the `promise1`. I find this weird. What is the logical reasoning behind this? To me it seems like an unnecessary complication and even a bad practice. Yet another `gotcha` which one needs to remember when working with JavaScript. But OK... I am sure smart people decided to take this approach so... what is the reasoning behind this decision? Any ideas?

```
    function onSuccess () {
      console.log('Success occurred!')
    }

    function onError () {
      console.log('Error occurred!')
    }

    const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        reject()
      }, 2000)
    })

    var p1 = promise.then(onSuccess);

    var p2 = p1.catch(onError); // 1 //
    // var p2 = promise.catch(onError); // 2 //

    console.log("DONE!");
```

Comment: If someone could suggest to me a better title for this question, I am OK to change it.

Comment: Why the downvote? These are pretty valid questions and are above mid-level JavaScript knowledge. Both of the questions are.

Comment: You can chain `.then()`s, and keep doing something else with the result. If `.then()` returned the original promise, you couldn't chain them.

Comment: @ChrisG Oh... OK... that's so obvious... I think this answers my second question, thanks. So that is the reason really...? What about the first question?

Comment: I didn't downvote but...you're asking for an opinion on the language design decision, which, since most if not all of us didn't write the ECMAScript spec, we probably can't give you. So that might be why people don't like the question. Opinion based questions are off-topic. If you simply ask how you can make the code work the way you want it to, people can give you practical, verifiable answers, which is what this site is all about

Comment: @ADyson It's not an opinion I am asking for. I am asking for some facts and some help in thinking. I am asking for an in-depth thinking, some logical reasoning behind this. Maybe somebody read something (in a book or blog) which explains why it was designed this way. As you can see ChrisG already gave a pretty good argument. At least it seems a good argument to me, and it's a simple one too. That 2nd question came to me after experimenting with this code and as a consequence of the 1st question.

Comment: Yes but since we didn't write the spec, we haven't got the facts about the designers' exact thinking...so consequently all you will get us people's personal thoughts on why it might be like that. And those are necessarily going to be opinions and not hard facts, unless you can find somewhere online where the originators of the spec are discussing their methodology. But if you can find that, then you don't need us to tell you.

Comment: @ADyson Yeah, well, OK... taken from this point of view, I agree. But I don't see how these 2 are bad questions. "But if you can find that, then you don't need us to tell you." That's also true. But if I don't find such a discussion online, I think SO is not a bad place to ask.

Comment: @ADyson or maybe he didn't find the answers he was looking for, therefore came to SO to do what we all came to do here- find answers to questions we could not answer ourselves

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your first question, this is quite simple:

You have 2 promise object when you get to those lines you mentioned: one is held by `promise` variable, and the other by `p1` variable. When you chain the `catch` directly to `promise`, it does not apply to the promise that is coming back from the `then` chaining - which is stored in `p1`- so you get `unhandled promise rejection error` on the **promise that comes back from the `then` clause**.

But, when you chain it to `p1`, which is already chained to `promise`, then the `catch` clause covers them both so no error here.

The difference essentailly is that line //1 can catch rejections / errors both from the original promise and then `.then` promise, but line //2 catches only rejects from original promise, leaving rejectes from the `.then` unhandled.

About 2nd question I'm sorry, but too high level for me and I don't wanna give incomplete / inaccurate answer.